# Wamp URL localhost issues

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost, wamp

So I had installed Wamp and had it running fine. I just fired it up today and noticed it isn't working properly.

Lets say I want to view the files in the game folder.

so http://localhost/game/index.php

what it seems to do is go to http://game/index.php and misses the localhost part.

Another thing I noticed is in the Apache logs.

it shows cann't find file F:\wamp\www\fav.jpg

but the fav file is in the game folder.

So it's making me wonder if some where some paths are not set correctly?

Even the index.php cannot load the database, even though the tables exit and have the correct database logins.

Comment: I'm sure someone can help better than i can, but you might google "moving wordpress". one of the things involved is changing the relative paths...hth

Comment: check your apache httpd.conf to see if directory mapping is ok. also check c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc to see if "hosts" file has this line "127.0.0.1 localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Although i bet it isn't your problem, are you running Skype while trying to use WAMP? If so, then that's the problem because they both use the same ports.

Comment: yeah I hear about it.. but no luckily I do not use or have skype at all.

Comment: The Skype Issue Addressed: you can fix that by un-checking option in skype preferences ->advance tab->connection. then you can use both wamp and skype together.. just to let people know who don't :)

Answer (score 0):

If your Wamp Server Model is **Wamp Server 3.0.6**, just right click it, then point your mouse to Wamp Settings and enable **Add localhost in url**... this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can update "urlAddLocalhost" variable in "wamp64/wampmanager.conf" file to on/off. By default it is "off".
My wamp version is 3.0.6.

```
urlAddLocalhost = "off"
```

[image]